# HAPI HL7 Validator does not validate parsed messages

Tags: hl7, hapi

The scenario when I parse and validate HL7 message at once works as expected:

```
HapiContext hapiContext = new DefaultHapiContext();
PipeParser parser = hapiContext.getPipeParser();
Message message = parser.parse("MSH|^~\\&|MedSeries|CAISI_1-2|PLS|3910|200903230934||ADT^A31^ADT_A05|75535037-1237815294895|P^T|2.5\r"
            + "EVN|A31|200903230934345345345345345\r"
            + "PID|1||29^^CAISI_1-2^PI~\"\"||Test300^Leticia^^^^^L||19770202|M||||||||||||||||||||||");
```

Exception (this is a valid behavior):

```
Exception in thread "main" ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.DataTypeException: ca.uhn.hl7v2.validation.ValidationException: Validation failed: Primitive value '200903230934345345345345345' requires to be empty or a HL7 datetime string at EVN-2(0)
```

But when I try first to parse HL7 message and then validate - validation method returns true and no exceptions are thrown:

```
HapiContext hapiContext = new DefaultHapiContext();
hapiContext.setValidationContext((ValidationContext) ValidationContextFactory.noValidation());
PipeParser parser = hapiContext.getPipeParser();
Message message = parser.parse("MSH|^~\\&|MedSeries|CAISI_1-2|PLS|3910|200903230934||ADT^A31^ADT_A05|75535037-1237815294895|P^T|2.5\r"
            + "EVN|A31|200903230934345345345345345\r"
            + "PID|1||29^^CAISI_1-2^PI~\"\"||Test300^Leticia^^^^^L||19770202|M||||||||||||||||||||||");


hapiContext.setValidationRuleBuilder(new DefaultValidationBuilder());
System.out.println(hapiContext.getMessageValidator().validate(message));
```

I need this to generate Acknowledgment messages in case validation fails using message.generateACK() method.

Answer (score 4):

You disabled validation for parsing with this:

`hapiContext.setValidationContext((ValidationContext) ValidationContextFactory.noValidation());`

But you are using the same context to validate your message, with validation still disable, that may be the root cause.

Also, did you try this? `context.getParserConfiguration().setValidating(false);` or true

Comment: 1) when I disable validation, I enable it back with setValidationRuleBuilder. Internally it calls setValidationContext, so a different context is used.

2) setValidating(false) instead of setValidationContext(noValidation) disables the validation, but when I set it to true in the next line and call hapiContext.getMessageValidator().validate(message) - it still returns true, no validation exception is thrown.